# Macro to find and move specific cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I need a macro that finds each cell in (Excel) column `A` that begins with an `*`  (asterisk plus space) and moves it one cell to the right and one cell up.

Then goes to the next `*`  cell in column `A` and does the same, and the next... until the end of the file.

My version of Excel (2023 V.16.72 for Mac) does not seem to have a way of putting the Macro tab in the tab lineup, and does not have "File" header in that lineup... although I can access the VBA using the "Tools" header in the Mac tab selections at top of frame.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution. It uses arrays and would probably be faster if used on large data. You didn't mention if you wanted to do anything with the empty spaces this creates in the A column so I just left them there.

```vb
Sub moveAsterisk()
    Dim lastRow As Long, wsh As Worksheet
    Set wsh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = wsh.Range("A" & wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim sourceArr() As Variant, sourceRange As Range
    Set sourceRange = wsh.Range("A1:B" & lastRow)
    sourceArr = sourceRange
    
    Dim curVal As String
    For i = 1 To UBound(sourceArr)
        curVal = sourceArr(i, 1)
        If Left(curVal, 2) = "* " Then
            sourceArr(i, 1) = ""
            sourceArr(i - 1, 2) = curVal
        End If
    Next
    sourceRange = sourceArr
End Sub
```

**input:**

[image]

**output:**

[image]

Comment: Many thanks.  I will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, such tasks are performed by going through all the cells one at a time:

```
Sub ReorderValues()
Dim rangeToReorder As Range ' All cells from A2 to the end of data
Dim oCell As Range          ' Single cell in column A
    Set rangeToReorder = Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, [A:A]).Offset(1, 0)
    For Each oCell In rangeToReorder.Cells
        If Left(oCell.Text, 2) = "* " Then
            oCell.Copy Destination:=oCell.Offset(-1, 1)
            oCell.ClearContents
        End If
    Next oCell
End Sub
```

But there is another way, without a macro. Place formulas like
`=IF(LEFT($A1;2)="* ";"";$A1)` and
`=IF(LEFT($A2;2)="* ";$A2;"")`
in the auxiliary cells to the right of your data, fill the columns with these formulas to the end of the data and copy the resulting values into the original columns A:B. Now the auxiliary cells can be cleared.

If necessary, this sequence of actions can also be written as a macro:

```
Sub QuickReorderValues()
Dim fullData As Range
Dim firstEmptyCell As Range
Dim newValues As Range
    Set fullData = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set firstEmptyCell = [A1].Offset(0, fullData.Columns.Count + 1)
    firstEmptyCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEFT(RC1,2)=""* "","""",RC1)"
    firstEmptyCell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEFT(R[1]C1,2)=""* "",R[1]C1,"""")"
    Set newValues = firstEmptyCell.Resize(fullData.Rows.Count, 2)
    newValues.FillDown
    fullData.Resize(, 2).Value2 = newValues.Value2
    newValues.ClearContents
End Sub
```

*Under some conditions (for example, for large datasets or when column B already contains some values that should be discarded), the second option is preferable.*

Comment: Many thanks. I will try these out.